# camera parsing data error

Tags: android, parsing, camera

I have time to time this camera error, I m not able to solve it

any idea (xperia X8)

> E/SemcCameraHardware(1241): receiveRawSnapshot: remove_padding_data()
>   failed, error while parsing the data from the camera!

Answer (score 2):

```
Tre this code

 public class CameraPreview extends Activity {
private Preview mPreview;
Camera mCamera;
int numberOfCameras;
int cameraCurrentlyLocked;

// The first rear facing camera
int defaultCameraId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hide the window title.
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
    // and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new Preview(this);
    setContentView(mPreview);

    // Find the total number of cameras available
    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    // Find the ID of the default camera
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
 }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    cameraCurrentlyLocked = defaultCameraId;
    mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
    // important to release it when the activity is paused.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mPreview.setCamera(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate our menu which can gather user input for switching camera
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.camera_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.switch_cam:
        // check for availability of multiple cameras
        if (numberOfCameras == 1) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(this.getString(R.string.camera_alert))
                   .setNeutralButton("Close", null);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            return true;
        }

        // OK, we have multiple cameras.
        // Release this camera -> cameraCurrentlyLocked
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        // Acquire the next camera and request Preview to reconfigure
        // parameters.
        mCamera = Camera
                .open((cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1) % numberOfCameras);
        cameraCurrentlyLocked = (cameraCurrentlyLocked + 1)
                % numberOfCameras;
        mPreview.switchCamera(mCamera);

        // Start the preview
        mCamera.startPreview();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

/**
      * A simple wrapper around a Camera and a SurfaceView that renders a centered preview of the Camera
 * to the surface. We need to center the SurfaceView because not all devices have cameras that
 * support preview sizes at the same aspect ratio as the device's display.
 */

```
 class Preview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private final String TAG = "Preview";

SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
Size mPreviewSize;
List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
Camera mCamera;

Preview(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    addView(mSurfaceView);

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    mCamera = camera;
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        requestLayout();
    }
}

public void switchCamera(Camera camera) {
   setCamera(camera);
   try {
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
   } catch (IOException exception) {
       Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
   }
   Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
   requestLayout();

   camera.setParameters(parameters);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
    // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
    // of stretching it.
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
        final View child = getChildAt(0);

        final int width = r - l;
        final int height = b - t;

        int previewWidth = width;
        int previewHeight = height;
        if (mPreviewSize != null) {
            previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
            previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
        }

        // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
        if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
            final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
            child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                    (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
        } else {
            final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
            child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                    width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
        }
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.
    try {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
}


private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
    requestLayout();

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}

}
```

and permissions also use

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html